# In Outlook or Mail.app are images for a gmail account pulled from google image proxy servers or original servers?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail, apple-mail

When using Outlook to access a gmail account, will images get pulled from the google image proxy servers or from the original servers?

From https://support.google.com/mail/answer/145919?hl=en

> How Gmail makes images safe
>   Some senders try to use externally linked images in harmful ways, but Gmail takes action to ensure that images are loaded safely. Gmail serves all images through Google’s image proxy servers and transcodes them before delivery to protect you in the following ways:
>
> Senders can’t use image loading to get information like your IP address or location.
>   Senders can’t set or read cookies in your browser.
>   Gmail checks your images for known viruses or malware.
>   In some cases, senders may be able to know whether an individual has opened a message with unique image links. As always, Gmail scans every message for suspicious content and if Gmail considers a sender or message potentially suspicious, images won’t be displayed and you’ll be asked whether you want to see the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you answered your own question

> "Gmail serves all images through Google’s image proxy servers"

Comment: Not really. I have a gmail address. I understand that if I access it from gmail.com that it will go through the image proxy server. However, it doesn't address if it goes through the proxy if I access via Outlook.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.